NextAuth with Keycloak: Logout Clears Session in Next.js but Not in Keycloak
I am trying to implement a OAUTH2 login using Keycloak through next-auth in a NextJS application, everything works fine except for the logout, indeed when I do logout the session gets cleared from my web application but the keycloack's session doesn't get terminated as well.
I tried managing logout using a few enpoints given by keycloack docks (ex.    /protocol/openid-connect/logout, /protocol/openid-connect/revoke) and even if they return 200 session from keycloak does not get cleared, is it any endpoint/library method I can use to invalidate keycloak's session as well?

This is my solution on the latest version of Next.js (currently major 14) and Keycloak (currently major 25)
           console.log('Signing out', process.env);
            let url = `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL || "localhost:3001")}`;
            url += token.idToken ? `&id_token_hint=${token.idToken}` : `&client_id=${process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}`;

            const res = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            });


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
